# LINQ - Merge parent and child data

Tags: c#, linq, merge

I am new to linq and trying to figure this list merge out. I am trying to merge 2 lists of parent/child data as follows:

```
{
    "ParentsList1": 
    [
        {
            "Name": "Parent 1",
                "Children": [
                    {
                        "Name": "Child 1",
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Child 2",
                    }
                ],
        },
          {
            "Name": "Parent 2",
                "Children": [
                    {
                        "Name": "Child 1",
                    }
                ],
          }
    ]
}
```

---

```
{
    "ParentsList2": 
    [
        {
            "Name": "Parent 1",
                "Children": [
                    {
                        "Name": "Child 1",
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Child 2",
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Child 3",
                    }
                ],
        },
          {
            "Name": "Parent 2",
                "Children": [
                    {
                        "Name": "Child 2",
                    }
                ],
          }
    ]
}
```

---------------Merged Output----------------

```
{
    "MergedParentsList": 
    [
        {
            "Name": "Parent 1",
                "Children": [
                    {
                        "Name": "Child 1",
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Child 2",
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Child 3",
                    }
                ],
        },
          {
            "Name": "Parent 2",
                "Children": [
                    {
                        "Name": "Child 2",
                    }
                ],
          }
    ]
}
```

I would like the merge to remove/replace child entities. So far I have been stuck working with a union

```
List<ParentListModel> mergedParentLists = ParentsList1
    .Union(ParentsList2)                                                                         
    .GroupBy(grp => new {grp.Name})
    .Select(sel => sel.FirstOrDefault())
    .ToList();
```

This seems to get the Parent list ok but cannot seem to sync up the child data...

Comment: Are you trying to get a union of the `Children` sets? Or are you trying to `remove/replace` `Children` that are in the union?

Comment: Your output is the same as the second list, so it's not obvious how merging it with the first list didn't result in any differences.

Comment: If you remove everything and replace it with the second list, why not just assign it to the second list? There does not appear to be any "merging" happening above... `MergedParentsList == ParentsList2` (maybe you just need better sample data, though).

Comment: Sorry, my question sucks... lol. I need to retain the parent entities from the first list, add any new parent entities from the second and then merge the children so that parentlist2 wins... does this make sense ?

Comment: It sounds like you're considering a person to be identical if they have the same name, so if you join two lists then parents who share the same name should be "merged" into one person, and in this process, their list of children should be merged in the same way (if they both have a child named "Child 1", then after the merge there will be only one "Child 1").

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "ParentList2 wins", though...? Do you mean that any unique children that a parent in `ParentList1` has will be abandoned if there is a matching parent name in `ParentList2`? Or, in other words, only take parents from `ParentList1` that don't exist in `ParentList2`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're considering a person to be identical if they have the same `Name`, so if you join two lists then any parents who share the same name should be "merged" into one person, and in this process, their children should be merged in the same way (if they both have a child named "Child 1", then after the merge there will be only one "Child 1", but otherwise all children from both instances of the parent exist in the merged instance of the parent).

If this is the case, then I think what you want to do is `Select new Person()` from your group, where you take the group `Key` as the person's name, and add the children by using `SelectMany` on all the children in the group and then taking only the unique ones by using `DistinctyBy(child.Name)`.

For example:

```
List<ParentListModel> mergedParents = parentList1
    .Union(parentList2)
    .GroupBy(parent => parent.Name)
    .Select(group =>
        new ParentListModel
        {
            Name = group.Key,
            Children = group
                .SelectMany(parent => parent.Children)
                .DistinctBy(child => child.Name)
                .ToList()
        })
    .ToList();
```

---

Also, there is some ambiguity in your question, where in the comments you mentioned that during a merge, `parentList2` should "win". If by this you mean you want to only add parents from `parentList1` that don't exist in `parentList2`, then you can simply do an `AddRange` where you add parents whose name doesn't exist in `parentList2`:

```
parentList2.AddRange(parentList1.Where(pl1Parent =>
    parentList2.All(pl2Parent => pl2Parent.Name != pl1Parent.Name)));
```

---

The ambiguity exists because your example holds true for both of these scenarios. It would be better if you included an example that excluded one of these (for example, if `Parent 1` in `parentList1` had a child named `Child 9`...would that child exist in the final merge or not?).